# Darkest hour, the beast which brings madness

Tags: biology, creature-design, evolution, xenobiology, fauna

Darkest hour is a flying creature who usually lives in the depths of the ocean. Once a year we see the darkest hour exits the waters and fly into the sky which will turn foggy and dark.

[image]

The Darkest hour flies around for about an hour and wherever it goes, darkness follows. When humans enter the area of effect of a darkest hour they lose control of their minds, it is common for people falling victims to the darkest hour to go on a killing spree or mutilating and killing themselves.

In order for people to correctly defend themselves and survive the coming of a darkest hour. how does the mechanism of induced uncontrolled violence work and why it exists?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Mary we need to know how does the mechanism of induced uncontrolled violence work and why it exists.

Comment: this isn't something you ask in world building. this is more like something you research and come to your own conclusion about. this stack exchange is for more scientific things, with active specific answers and questions. like "how would a meteor affect a pluto-like world" in which you provide specific measurements, the  amount of damage, and then you ask if it's accurate, or ask if anyone who is smarter than you can find out how much damage it deals, or how big the meteor would look. stack exchange isn't for open ended questions.

Comment: @michaelgriffin how is it an open ended question? How is it different than asking "how does this creature breathe fire?" Of which many questions like that have been asked, to the thousands.

Comment: I think the question is asking what in the fog creates the effect to the people, im thinking something chemical which induces a rabies like rage.

Comment: well yes, it is akin to "how does this creature breathe fire" but it's still too open ended. there are many things that can make humans and animals irritated, and many things that can let animals and humans breathe fire. it can also just be magic. the thing is that this is like asking 

"why did the chicken cross the road" there are many reasons why. there are also many reasons why your humans get suicidal and homicidal in the presence of the darkest hour

Comment: I didn't use the magic tag, I never do.

Comment: reread my comment, i edited it.

Comment: The "why it exists" part is squarely off-topic. WB isn't a site for providing reasons for plot elements. I would suggest editing that out.

Comment: This query hasn't been edited in over a year; it should be left closed until OP clarifies. It's an interesting scenario!

Answer (score 5):

Darkest Hour generates very strong **magnetic fields** which cause [magnetically induced hallucinations](https://www.technologyreview.com/2010/05/11/203417/magnetically-induced-hallucinations-explain-ball-lightning-say-physicists/) in human brains. Laboratory tests show that exposing certain parts of the human brain to a 0.5 Tesla magnetic field can cause all kinds of different hallucinations.

The primary reason why Darkest Hour generates these electromagnetic fields could be that they are part of how its able to levitate. The effect on any humans in the area might just be coincidental.

Comment: dang, i was literally typing up a magnetic field effect answer! but mine included that it would be very lovecraftian for the creature to not even notice, mean, or care about making the people go mad. ah well +1 for you instead

Comment: Those experiments are done with a magnet right on the person's head. Considering the distance of the effect of the Darkest Hour, the field it would produce would be horrendously powerful. Have you considered other possible effects of such a field? Would it suck up metal that is directly under it? Could it explain how the creature levitates?

Answer (score 4):

I mean, as far as it seems, we're talking about a giant sea "thing" that can somehow fly, whose very presence causes the sky to darken. Saying it just happens, that it's due to magic or that it's a simply a byproduct of its reality bending abilities (because by your description I am 99% certain that this thing most likely came from another dimension) all seem like valid answers in this scenario.

However, trying to make it as realistic as possible within science fiction territory and considering it has an "area of effect", we can likely rule out options like pheromones in the air, since those won't stay in a determined open area, will not cease having effect immediately after the person leaves said area and won't work exclusively on humans. My best guess here would be that the creature has psionic capabilities, directly influencing any humans within its reach. Upon a finding a human within reach, it will take control of its mind, numbing conscience, inducing a strong release of adrenaline in the body and passing the idea that other humans are a threat. Things like "the call of the void", in which a person wielding a knife can get a heads up from their brain that they could use the knife they're holding to stab the person doing the dishes right next to them exist, so this would be an extreme version aggravated by the state of aggression they're in.

Though many other potential ways to trigger extreme aggression in humans are possible, I don't think any realistic, existing method would attend all of the requirements (works in an area of effect style and only affects humans). Your Darkest hour isn't that different from an earthquake or a hurricane, and understanding how the earthquake works doesn't mean we can stop it, only that we might be able to detect it quicker and mitigate its effects. This thing is essentially a friendlier version of how a sentient natural disaster would behave if lovecraft had a say in it. You can't defend against it, only get out of its way until it quiets down. If you can't get out of the way, Restrain everyone until it has passed, so that the people won't go on a killing spree.

Comment: +1 for the call of the void thing, never knew it was common...now I know that I'm not crazy.  I ignored the flying part because there are already too many questions about giant flying animals, found 3 different ones just by looking up flying whales. The part of the sky darkening I left it to the imagination of others, not sure if I will ask a question about it in the future, if you or anyone else wanted to ask about the mechanism of how an animal brings darkness wherever it goes, feel free to use my ideas....they are not even mine, it's 2020...nothing is original, and it's fine!

Comment: @Vesrei talk about it. You create a character, give it abilities and then months later you find out later about a show/comic which makes it look like you stole the idea from them. The darkening of the clouds could be simply a side effect of it bending reality (the sky darkening when a giant demonic-looking thing that induces madness is usually explained that way, and honest it distorting reality sounds like the most plausible explanation here).

Answer (score 2):

I will limit my answer to the questioned part and don't discuss flying, darkening and so on here. ^^

One possibility for this effect on humans could **pain induced frenzy** be. In this case, the darkest hour emitts a really high pitched permanent sound, slightly above the area humans can hear but heavy enough to cause severe pain within a humans ears and head. By triggering the right areas of the brain (by a combination of the pain, fear and the wavelengths the darkest hour emitts which stimmulate certain areas) it causes a frenzy like state in its victims driving them to kill people and animals, destroy things and finally kill themselvs if the pain continues. As you didn't define criterias for the area of effect I think there will be no problem if in the outer zones of the AoE the humans will have headaches but will not act that aggressive.

Answer (score 1):

Barring psionics you'd have to assume some form of secreted hallucinogenic.

For which the simplest defense would simply be take a strong dose of a fast acting drug that renders the consumer unconscious for 2-3 hours as soon the changing light conditions that accompany the creatures emergence are noticed and an alarm is raised. Everyone simply carries a vial with them during the relevant time of year wherever they go 24/7.

Even a simple cloth mask and a bottle of chloroform would probably do the tick assuming a properly measured dose.

Answer (score 0):

The sky gets dark and foggy due to all the water the beast is displacing - a lot of it will go into the atmosphere, where it will block sunlight (think of very think clouds, in some cases they can make day seem like night). On top of that the mist and the rain contain a mix of very fine-grained cocaine, as well as some other narcotic substances.

Wearing hazmat suits should protect a person from the mind-altering effects. And if you wish to battle this creature, I say nuke it from orbit.

Answer (score 0):

Lets try to look at it from its point of view.

First off, it is **not** a sea creature.  A sea creature wouldn't be flying.  It is a creature that is capable of living in the sea, at least for a time.  It might well have some shape-shifting abilities such that most of the time it looks completely different and causes no problems.  It might even appear human and live among humans.

What is it doing?  I suspect it is looking for a mate.  Driven by biological urges and seasonal variation, it puts on a mating display trying to find a partner.  The insanity is a result of the pheromones or psychic emanations it releases.

Why does it fail?  Well, it is probably a non-native species and there is only one present.   Whether it is from another dimension, or another planet, or just the last of its kind is up to you.  If humans are a recent arrival, they could have killed off the other gender of the species.

As for the darkness?  That could be part of its flight mechanism, part of a display, clouds of pheromones, another mental effect on humans, or something messing up the vision of humans.  (The last two would affect people present but not video cameras.)